# Which android api can replace GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance ios API?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I am currently porting the ios map app to android.
GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance api I can't find what the corresponding android api is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-) from [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility):

> ```
> public static boolean isLocationOnPath(LatLng point,
>                                    java.util.List<LatLng> polyline,
>                                    boolean geodesic,
>                                    double tolerance)
> ```
>
> Computes whether the given point lies on or near a polyline, within a
>   specified tolerance in meters. The polyline is composed of great
>   circle segments if geodesic is true, and of Rhumb segments otherwise.
>   The polyline is not closed -- the closing segment between the first
>   point and the last point is not included.

Maps SDK for Android Utility Setup steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup).

You can use it this way:

```
...
for (LatLng point : redPolyline.getPoints()) {
    if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(point, path.getPoints(), true, 50)) {
        // point is on path
        ...
    }
}
```

where `50` - is tolerance (in meters).